# mongodb multiple logical operator with $match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, logical-operators

What is the mongodb agg `$match` equivalent to this `sql`?

```
SELECT a FROM DB_A WHERE (t > 21 AND a.t < 60) OR s = 'value'
```

This mongodb query does not work. Any help?

```
db.collection_a.aggregate([
     { '$match': { '$and': [ {'t': {'$gte': '21'}}, {'t': {'$lte': '60'}}  ] 
    //, '$or': [ {'s': 'value'} ]
            } 
            ,{ '$or': [ {'s': 'value'} ]}
     }

]);
```

Comment: What was the reason for removing the `$project` stage from your original question?

Comment: well nothing special. just remove unnecessary line

Comment: It is not just removing unnecessary lines, the `$and` conditions in this case need not be box bracketed, conditions are implicitly treated using the `$and` operator.

Comment: Thanks for down vote

Answer (score 3):

Your [syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#examples) is totally messed up. It should be:

```
db.a.aggregate([
{$match:{$or:[{"t":{$lte:60,$gte:21}},
              {"s":"value"}]}},
{$project:{"test_type": 1, "distance": 1}}
])
```